# Exported Fbx has invisible parts

Tags: texturing, uv, export

When I exported my fbx (with Path copy and all  normals facing out/blue).
The results of my fbx ends up turning the hands and gun invisible.

[image]

What further frustrates me is that it knows there are two UV's (The glove having the same UV as the body) and it acknowledges the hand and gun. But it refuses to display it... WHY????
THe normals are fine (I already flipped them and still the same results) and all meshes are joined as one. I've exported meshes with two uv's before and they displayed everything. WHat is blender doing?
[image]

Comment: can you share your file with https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Apparently it's too large.

Comment: Don't pack the textures or try doing a `File` -> `Clean Up` or upload on dropbox

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fully export all objects and textures using gtlf instead of fbx.

I get downvoted for solving my own problem?